# Setting background property through Style in code does not work, but setting it directly does

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview

I'm trying to set a style for a border's background color, the strange things is if I do it like this it works:

```
var borders = this.Editor.ChildrenOfType<Border>().Where(x => x.Name == "Background_Selected");
foreach (var border in borders)
{
    border.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
```

But I want (need) to do it like this:

```
var borders = this.Editor.ChildrenOfType<Border>().Where(x => x.Name == "Background_Selected");
foreach (var border in borders)
{
    var style = new Style(typeof(Border));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter()
    {
        Property = BackgroundProperty,
        Value = Brushes.Red
    });

    border.Style = style;
}
```

What is going on here? why can't I set it with a style but can set it directly.

**EDIT**

The reason i need to do it like that is because I want to set this background color depending on a value of a bound object (which I was planning on setting like this):

```
var borders = this.Editor.ChildrenOfType<Border>().Where(x => x.Name == "Background_Selected");
foreach (var border in borders)
{
    var binding = new Binding();
    binding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.TemplatedParent);
    binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Value.IsSelected");
    binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

    var style = new Style(typeof(Border));
    var trigger1 = new DataTrigger()
    {
        Binding = binding,
        Value = true
    };

    trigger1.Setters.Add(new Setter()
    {
        Property = BackgroundProperty,
        Value = Brushes.Green
    });

    var trigger2 = new DataTrigger()
    {
        Binding = binding,
        Value = false
    };

    trigger2.Setters.Add(new Setter()
    {
        Property = BackgroundProperty,
        Value = Brushes.Red
    });

    style.Triggers.Add(trigger1);
    style.Triggers.Add(trigger2);

    border.Style = style;
}
```

Comment: Do the Buttons have an explicitly set Background before you apply the Style?

Comment: @Clemens If you mean like this: <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}"> Then yes, Removing it changes nothing though

Comment: No, I mean a so-called local value, like `<Border Background="Gray" .../>`. That would always have higher priority than a value from a Style Setter.

Comment: @Clemens yes, yes it does

Comment: @Clemens Removing it does not seem to make a difference though, removing all styling from the border and all other elements does not seem to change anything